# Scan computer memory

Tags: winapi, memory

How to search given sequence of bytes in a computer memory? ReadProcessMemory API does not suit because it only reads process memory, not whole memory.

Is there any existent solutions?

Comment: Windows has that fancy feature called 'protected memory' that keeps people from doing that. Perhaps someone will come with a "better" solution, but if you need to read the physical memory, as far as I know, you need to live in kernel space; consequently, you have to write a driver.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Device\PhysicalMemory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787565%28WS.10%29.aspx) object, but mind that user-mode access is not permitted for some Windows versions (see the link). If you want to use it, you'll find [this article](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/~dquigley/files/vista_security/p59-0x10_Playing_with_Windows_dev%28k%29mem.txt) useful (search for "5.2 chmod_mem.c" for some sample code).

Answer (score 1):

Due to the virtual memory and paging, you may not find the sequence in the physical memory.

Enumerating the processes and [heap walking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366710%28VS.85%29.aspx) is one way to scan the memory, except the kernel memory.